# Macro expansion in TikZ node

Tags: tikz-pgf, expansion, expl3

I am having some problems with macro expansion in TikZ nodes. The MWE below is supposed to draw nodes at specified coordinates and display their coordinate rounded to the nearest number, but it shows the coordinates of the last node for both of them.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \x
\tl_new:N \x_round

\NewDocumentCommand \mynode { m } {
    \tl_set:Nn \x { 
        \fp_eval:n { #1 } 
    }

    \tl_set:Nn \x_round { 
       \fp_eval:n { round ( \x ) } 
    }

    \addplot [style={mark=none}] coordinates { ( \x , \x ) } node { \x_round } ;
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}            
            \mynode{1.1}
            \mynode{2.2}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I assume the problem is that the `\x_round` is not expanded in the node until the end of the environments. How can I ensure `\x_round` is expanded immediately?

I have noticed that replacing the command with

```
\NewDocumentCommand \mynode { m } {
    \addplot [style={mark=none}] coordinates { ( #1 , #1 ) } node { \fp_eval:n { round ( #1 ) }  } ;
}
```

does fix the problem, but for my real code, it is inadequate as the code is more complex.

Comment: `\x` is a blasphemy regarding `expl3` naming convention ;-)

Comment: Hehe, I wanted to keep it simple for the MWE. My actual code as proper naming ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `\tl_set:Nx`, but it's quite pointless anyway:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand \mynode { m }
 {
  \addplot [style={mark=none}]
    coordinates { ( \fp_eval:n { #1 } , \fp_eval:n { #1 } ) }
    node { \fp_eval:n { round(#1) } } ;
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \mynode{1.1}
    \mynode{2.2}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Avoid names such as `\x` and `\x_round`, use the proper naming conventions.

[image]

You can use variables (here I use `fp` ones, but `tl` can be good as well, provided you set them with `\tl_set:Nx`). However, text in the node has to be expanded before passing it to PGF:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\fp_new:N \l_slo_coord_x_fp
\fp_new:N \l_slo_coord_x_round_fp

\NewDocumentCommand \mynode { m }
 {
  \fp_set:Nn \l_slo_coord_x_fp { #1 }
  \fp_set:Nn \l_slo_coord_x_round_fp { round ( \l_slo_coord_x_fp ) }
  \use:x
   {
    \exp_not:N \addplot [style={mark=none}]
      coordinates { ( \fp_use:N \l_slo_coord_x_fp , \fp_use:N \l_slo_coord_x_fp ) }
      node { \fp_use:N \l_slo_coord_x_round_fp } ;
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    \mynode{1.1}
    \mynode{2.2}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps worth using an auxiliary? I'd tend to avoid evaluating the same expression multiple times, both for efficiency and as it could have a random component.

Comment: @JosephWright It doesn't really work here, because one has to expand the argument to `node`.

Comment: Thanks, it works great. I actually tried using \tl_set:Nx, but I guess node has to be unexpanded if I understand things correctly, right?

Comment: Can you add some explanation what you fixed in the first case? (the expression to be computed is substituted directly into the node label (`\fp_eval:n { round(#1) }`), so even though `\addplot` only
expand it at the end of the environment, it evaluates to the correct result; on the other hand `\x_round` is dependent on the definition of that control sequence which is changed afterwards), I think?

Comment: @user202729 I'm not sure what youu mean by “expands it at the end of the environment”. What I can see is that the arguments are expanded when `\addplot` is executed. In the OP's version, `\x_round` was stored, not its value, so, at `\end{axis}` it received the last value.

Comment: @egreg I think in the first code above `\addplot` stores `\fp_eval:n { round(#1) }` for each node, which is
`\fp_eval:n { round(1.1) }` and `\fp_eval:n { round(2.2) }` respectively,
and only expand it to `1` and `2` at the end of the environment. -- i.e. just somehow explain what you did differently in the first code versus the OP 's,  since it's not obvious at all (you didn't use any `x`-type parameter expansion)

Comment: @user202729 Well, the code works, doesn't it? What's stored is what results *after* parameter substitution. So in the first case `\fp_eval:n { round(1.1) }`